# Where is the SQL outputting when setting show_sql in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

Where is the SQL outputting when setting show_sql in [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate)?

I have [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is outputted to the console.

But if you setup the log4net then you can get a logfile of everything that NHibernate does.

I do this programmatically and have a config file that specifies whether to do this or not. I found it better than setting in the hibernate configuration file

**Update**

I just had a look at the source code and their is a function called LogSqlInConsole() (Cfg.Loquacious.DbIntegrationConfiguration).

This is called from the Cfg.Loquacious.SettingsFactory which then says log.Info("echoing all SQL to stdout")

This is the log4net logger and I believe if you don't setup any configuration file it defaults to the console.